# Is the Apple Magic Trackpad 2 supported in Juno? With multitouch gestures?

Tags: touchpad, gesture

I [have read](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Apple-Magic-Trackpad-2) that Google engineers worked in an Apple Magic Trackpad 2 driver for Linux, back in September. Is this driver available in Juno? Can you use it with multitouch gestures support?

Comment: Can you provide a link to that info?

Comment: @Sebastian: Link added in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Magic Trackpad 2 support will only [land](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9d7b18668956c411a422d04c712994c5fdb23a4b) in Kernel 4.20, to be released in a few days. This kernel could come to elementary via the [Ubuntu Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) in February 2019, but I am not aware of any definitive announcement which kernel version that will contain.